# Is it possible to customise the creation and storage of Kubernetes service account token?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

Is it possible to customise how a Kubernetes service account is created?

Once created, is it possible to specify how it is stored?

I'd like to avoid storing the tokens as secrets if at all possible as I want them stored outside Kubernetes.

Comment: As far as I know, Service Account has a token, certificate and key which are created by Certificate Authority.Certificate Authority is part of API server. All of the components which needs to communicate with API Server, they need to have a token. For example, Kubelet access with its token to API Server in order to change the state of the cluster in Etcd.